# Trying to drag a dynamically created rectangle in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, draggable

I want to move a rectangle, which is dynamically drawn, via "mouse-dragging".
I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Layout;
using System.Windows.Interactivity; 



        Rectangle GreenROI = new Rectangle (referenceROI.x0, referenceROI.y0, referenceROI.width, referenceROI.height);

        g.DrawRectangle(referencePen, GreenROI);

// then I added the MouseDragElementBehaviour:

        MouseDragElementBehavior dragBehavior = new MouseDragElementBehavior();

        dragBehaviour.Attach(GreenROI);
```

This does not work and VS 2019 shows "Error CS1503 argument "1": Conversion from "System.Drawing.Rectangle" to "System.Windows.DependencyObject" not possible".
Anybody any other ideas how to solve it?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You don't want to use a WinForms `System.Drawing.Rectangle`, but a WPF `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle` instead.

Comment: @Clemens : Ok, that could be it. I got the task to add the "dragging the rectangles"-ability to an existing wpf c# project. I'll ask the programmer, who programmed the project file and ask him if he unknowningly used the `System.Drawing`, which has to be used for WinForms instead of the `System.Windows.Shapes`, which has to be used for WPF.

Comment: That *is* it. Be aware that you would usually not use anything from the System.Drawing namespace in a WPF application. You would also not have a reference to the System.Drawing assembly.

Comment: @Clemens: Ok, the person who programmed the whole project also used System.Drawing.Imaging besides System.Drawing and used it for a lot of rectangles and Bitmaps. That is going to be a long debugging.